# Adding a column to relation result in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a Car model and a Driver model

```
Car has_many :drivers
```

I have a query for recently driven cars by drivers with a specific rating

```
Car.recently_driven.joins(:drivers).merge(Driver.with_good_rating)
```

This would give me a list of cars.

How do I access the driver(s) for which these cars were selected in the query? or to rephrase, how can I attach a driver_id to the car rows that are resulted in the query?

**to further clarify my intents:**
I want the result of the above query will be the columns of the car, but with another column of a driver_id. So I can access the driver_id without querying it again

Answer (score 1):

```
Car.recently_driven.joins(:drivers).includes(:drivers).merge(Driver.with_good_rating) # will give you what you already have, but with reduced queryes
```

Then you could map your result, using `map`

```
Car.recently_driven.joins(:drivers).merge(Driver.with_good_rating).map do |car|
   [car, car.driver_ids]
end
```

will return:

```
[
   [car_object, driver_ids],
   ...
   [car_object, driver_ids],
]
```

You could try `DB` solution, not sure if it will work for your example.

```
cars = Car.recently_driven.joins(:drivers).includes(:drivers).merge(Driver.with_good_rating)
```

then

```
first_car = cars.first
driver_ids_f = first_car.driver_ids # it will not make DB query, it is loaded bot not shown
```

Comment: I have to do pass through the whole thing? Or is it because it was eager loaded it doesn't hurt?

Comment: It still does hurt, because this way you are making query to the DB, then parsing your data. It is slower then making query to DB that would do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

**To Get All Drivers  for which these cars were selected**

First get result in a local variable the way you do

```
cars = Car.recently_driven.joins(:drivers).merge(Driver.with_good_rating)
```

Then Get all drivers using

```
drivers = Driver.find_by(car_id: cars.pluck(:id))
```